# category the customers with binary status from pandas in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

Input:

```
df= {'Customer_ID':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],'A_Jan':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
     'A_Feb':[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],'A_Mar':[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],
     'A_Apr':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],'A_May':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
     'B_Jan':[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0],'B_Feb':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
     'B_Mar':[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],'B_Apr':[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0],
     'B_May':[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0]}
```

output:

```
df4={'Customer_ID':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],'A_Jan':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
     'A_Feb':[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],'A_Mar':[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],
     'A_Apr':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],'A_May':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
     'B_Jan':[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0],'B_Feb':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
     'B_Mar':[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],'B_Apr':[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0],
     'B_May':[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
     'Category':['Very good','Good','Good','avg','avg','poor','poor','very poor','very poor','not consider']}
```

I want to categories the customers with below rules in Python 3.6  
Category    --> Description  
 very good    --> both A and B are same status  
 good        ---> No change in A but rarely changing B status  
 Avg  ---> No change in A but rarely changing B status( continues zeros 2-3 times)   
 poor      ---> Rarely changing A status and continuously changing B status( continues zeros 2-3 times)  
 very poor   ---> Rarely changing A status and Alternating changing B status

> there is no rows like all values are 0 in my data.

> In a Banking sector, Column "A_" contains means Active customers or inactive and column "B_" contains means sent statement copies in email or physical.  
> if column "A_" contains 1 then it means he/she a active customer for particular month  
> if column "B_" contain 1 then it means company has sent some letter to customer in email , 0 means sent some letter in physical copy(post).  
> I wants to category the customers with above description.  
> Kindly comments if any concern. plz don't devote

[Below attached sample example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdtD.png)

Comment: Your input and output are not pandas dataframes but a python dictionary. Do you want a solution for dictionaries? What does `rarely changing` mean?

Comment: Rarely changing, for Good categories--> there no Change in "A_"columns but we can see the "B_"columns B_jan to B_may only one zero for 3,4 customers (out of 6 columns 5 ones we have) . Average categories--> There is no change in "A_columns" but "B_columns" has continously zeros  5,6 customers. poor category--> there is change in "A_columns as well as continuous zeros in "B_columns". Let me know if anything needed